# How to get plain text from Appointment.Details?

Tags: c#, uwp

I've tried to get the plain text from `Appointment.Details` instead of the html document.

I've found if the events were created by Microsoft calendar supplier, e.g. hotmail, the details of them would be presented in the html document instead of the plain text (BTW, if events are created by Gmail, their details are plaint text). I tried to get the plain text in the way below, but it doesn't work though.

```
var appointmentStore = await AppointmentManager.RequestStoreAsync(AppointmentStoreAccessType.AllCalendarsReadWrite);

FindAppointmentsOptions options = new FindAppointmentsOptions { MaxCount = 100 };
options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Subject);
options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.Details);
options.FetchProperties.Add(AppointmentProperties.DetailsKind);

DateTimeOffset startTime = new DateTimeOffset(new DateTime(2018, 2, 1));
// The UWP api gets the events from the Calendar app of Windows 10 OS.
List<Appointment> evtList = 
    (await appointmentStore.FindAppointmentsAsync(startTime, new TimeSpan(30, 0, 0, 0), options)).ToList();

foreach (var evt in evtList) {

    Debug.WriteLine(evt.Subject);

    // I've found if the events were created in Microsoft calendar supplier, e.g. hotmail,
    // the details of them would be the html document instead of the plain text.
    // I've tried to make the evt.Details presented in the plain text 
    // instead of the html document, but this way doesn't work.
    evt.DetailsKind = AppointmentDetailsKind.PlainText;

    Debug.WriteLine(evt.Details);
}
```

[image: Visual studio debug info]
[image: Add an event to hotmail in the Windows 10 Calendar app]

Actually I'm working in C++ environment which can also use the UWP APIs. I'm used to testing 
 and verifying the APIs in C# first.

Also, the UWP api, `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText()` can't fit my need sadly. In my C++ project, calling `HtmlUtilities.ConvertToText()` would cause the [Static Buffer Overruns](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms717795(v=vs.85).aspx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I've found if the events were created by Microsoft calendar supplier, e.g. hotmail, the details of them would be presented in the html document instead of the plain text (BTW, if events are created by Gmail, their details are plaint text).

Yep, this is special feature for "Microsoft calendar supplier" within calendar store application. You could use it to edit detail appointment with format.

[image]

If you want to convert the detail to plain text, you could use [`HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack.NetCore/) to parse html like following.

```
if (evt.DetailsKind == AppointmentDetailsKind.Html)
{
    HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
    doc.LoadHtml(evt.Details);

    var nodes = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//p[@class='MsoNormal']");
    foreach (var node in nodes)
    {
        var text = node.InnerText;
    }
}
```